# Чому відпустка "декретна"?

Tags: етимологія

У американців це називається *maternity leave* (також — *paternity leave*), що говорить само за себе.

Офіційно в нас є аж [два позначення](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/n0004323-14):

- відпустка у зв'язку з вагітністю та пологами
- відпустка для догляду за дитиною до досягнення нею трирічного віку

Жодне з них, із очевидних причин, не вживається в розмові. Натомість маємо *декретну відпустку*. Але походження цього слова далеко не таке очевидне, бо

> **[ДЕКРЕТ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21416&page=726)**
>
> 1. Постанова президентської, урядової, іншої найвищої виконавчої влади з якого-небудь питання, що має таку саму силу, як і закон. // іст. У СРСР до 1936 р. – акт найвищих органів державної влади та управління.

начебто не має безпосереднього відношення до пологів.

Comment: Угу, зрозуміло, постараюсь відійти від цієї назви.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Декретна відпустка" — це розмовна назва. Як ви правильно написали, з 1917 до 1936 року закони називалися декретами щоб відмежуватися від царської влади (міністерства називалися комісаріатами і т.і.).

Згідно з [Вікіпедією](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC#.D0.98.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F), вперше в Росії відпустка у зв'язку з вагітністю та пологами була введена у дію декретом Ради народних комісарів 14 (27) листопада 1917 року. Саме тому у пост-радянських країнах цю відпустку називають "декретною".

Словник СУМ також дає таке пояснення слову [декретний](http://sum.in.ua/s/dekretnyj):

> ДЕКРЕ́ТНИЙ, а, е. Установлений декретом. 
>   ▲ **Декретний час** — поясний час, переведений в СРСР на 1 годину вперед для повнішого використання населенням світлової частини доби. Іноді буває потрібно розрахувати, коли за нашим годинником, що йде за декретним часом, буде місцевий полудень (Воронцов-Вельямінов, Астрономія, 1956, 40); **Декретна відпустка** — відпустка по вагітності.

Comment: @Yola, щодо Вашого виправлення: в Вікіпедії (правда російській і без джерел) написано саме про світ, а не про Росію.

Comment: @Sasha У Бельгії така відпустка, теж на 4 тижні, була з 1889 року - [Parental leave entitlements: Historical perspective (around 1870 - 2014)](https://www.cesifo-group.de/ifoHome/facts/DICE/Social-Policy/Family/Work-Family-Balance/parental-leave-entitlements-historical-perspective/fileBinary/parental-leave-entitlements-historical-perspective.pdf)

Comment: У Бельгії 1870 була неоплачувана відпустка на 4 тижні, у Росії у 1917 році ввели оплачувану відпустку. Наскільки я зрозумів "оплачуваність" була "першою у світі".

Comment: Гляньте там Німеччину. Оплачувані два тижні відпустки перед родами уже з 1911, а може й 1903.

Comment: @Yola Ну, тоді все, питання першості закрито :)

Comment: @Yola, перед `пологами`, не `родами` :-)

Comment: @s0nata дякую, я ще думав, що якось дивно воно мені звучить:)